# trouble getting the data type from data base in c# .NET and the max length

Tags: c#, database

I am trying to figure out how to get the data type of each attribute in tables of database to use it for some verification example : i have the table : **declarant** in my sql database.
This table contains 4 attributes one of the attributes is : *mat_fisc* its datatype is numeric(7,0)

I wanted to retrieve the varchar datatype and the max length of the attribute (7)

the verification consists on : if i have a numeric attribute and the lenght of the data is < max length of the attribute then i have to add 0 till it fills all the space.

For example I have the attribute *mat_fisc*, its datatype is numeric(7,0) , and i have the data 1115 which contains 4 characters , then i have to fill it with 0 till the length attends 7 
then the data will become : **1115000**
How do we refer to the datatype and the max length in c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use the `getSchemaTable()` method on the `DataTableReader` class. The methods docs can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablereader.getschematable.aspx). Check out [this msdn article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310107) for a complete example. There is some setup required before you can call that method (ie you have to create a connection and execute a command so that you have a `DataTableReader` to call `getSchemaTable()` on). If you get something implemented and need help update your post with code and the specific problem and I'll try to help out.

Comment: thank you for your help , i did try something but it doesn't work it only displays : IsColumnSet System.Boolean here is the code

Answer (score 0):

the following code when i execute it expecting it to display all the column types and names it only displays : IsColumnSetSystem.Boolean

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string EF = textBox1.Text;

        try{
            //SqlDataAdapter adapter = SetupDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM id_declarant");
     SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
     string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=declaration;Integrated Security=True";
      comm.Connection=new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            String sql = @"SELECT * 
                  FROM id_declarant,declarant
                 WHERE (declarant.Nom_pren_RS='" + EF + "') and (id_declarant.mat_fisc=declarant.mat_fisc)  "; 
     comm.CommandText = sql;
  comm.Connection.Open();
             SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
             DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
             foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
             {
                 foreach (DataColumn column in schemaTable.Columns)
                 {
                     System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Manuela\Documents\GL4\WriteLines.txt", column.ColumnName + column.DataType );

                 }
             }
```